# I want to delete a row from a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm beginner in c++, and I want to make a program that delete a row from a matrix.. Like, If I say 3 3 2 
                        1 2 3 it need to show 1 2 3 
                        4 5 6                 7 8 9
                        7 8 9
The program works like this: 3 = rows, 3 = columns, 2 = the deleted row. "3 3 2" is not a row... 
I wrote this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int N, M, v[100][100];
  cin>>N>>M;
  int i,j,p;
  cin>>p;
  for (i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    for (j = 1; j <= M; ++j)
        cin>>v[i][j];
    for (i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
  for (j = 1; j <= M; ++j)
      cout<<v[i][j]<<" ";
   cout<<"\n";
    }
    for (i = p; i < N; ++i)
        v[i][j]=v[i+1][j];
    --N;
    for (i = 1; i <= N; ++i){
        for (j = 1; j <= N; ++j)
        cout<<v[i][j]<<' ';
    cout<<"\n";
}
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work.... Can someone help me?

Comment: *I want to make a program that delete a row from a matrix* -- Arrays cannot be resized.  So your question itself needs clarification.  What do you mean by "delete a row"?

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ is a pretty vague problem description ...

Comment: Also, arrays start at index 0, not 1.

Comment: *Can someone help me?* -- Yes, the help is that you can't use arrays to do this.  So your attempt is going to go nowhere.  Either use a standard container such as `std::vector`, or less advised, use dynamic allocation using `new[]`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are taking him too literally when he says delete, what he means is overwrite. Obviously that is possible with arrays.

Comment: @john -- Well that's why the question needs clarification.  Overwrite a row with what value?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well the next row obviously, and that row with the one after, all the way to the last row. With the net effect that the original row has been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified code (it will work fine ):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int N, M, v[100][100];
cin>>N>>M;
int i,j,p;
cin>>p;

for (i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    for (j = 1; j <= M; ++j)
        cin>>v[i][j];

for (i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= M; ++j)
        cout<<v[i][j]<<" ";
    cout<<"\n";
}

for (i = p; i < N; ++i)
    for(j=1; j<=M; ++j)
        v[i][j]=v[i+1][j];
--N;

for (i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= M; ++j)
        cout<<v[i][j]<<' ';
    cout<<"\n";
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Delete the second for.. Thank you a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, what do you think `j` is doing in this code?

```
for (i = p; i < N; ++i)
   v[i][j]=v[i+1][j];
--N;
```

You need to loop over rows and columns. Copy each column in every row greater that the row you want to delete. In other words you need nested loops here

```
for (i = p; i < N; ++i)
   for (j = 1; j <= M; ++j)
      v[i][j] = v[i+1][j];
--N;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `vector`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //matrix
    vector< vector<int> > V;

    //To Add
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        vector<int> R;
        for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
        {
            int x;
            cin>>x;
            R.push_back(x);
        }
        V.push_back(R);
    }
    //To delete a row
    int row_to_delete = 2;
    V.erase(V.begin() + row_to_delete);
    //To access
    for(int i=0; i<V.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<V[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout<<V[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

`vector<T>` is class that use a template to create a dynamic array.

`vector<int>` is a var array int. `V.push_back(T)` you can add a element to array with type T, and with `V.erase(V.begin() + int )` you can delete a element to array in this case a row. With `V.size()` you can take a elements count inside the array.